# .done attachment not working with ajax update to file, works with read from file

Tags: ajax, sql-update, promise

Attaching .done .fail and .always to ajax calls is now doable for me - it is "easy" when the script is at the bottom of the html page.

Now I want to create generalized ajax functions that I can use just by including a js file in the header. I've been successful with ajax functions that read data from server (.done always works). I'm having problems when I just write or update data to the server (no return of data). Here are the specifics-

Standard ajax add/update call that always works - in script tags at bottom of page.

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
         url: 'supdateajaxfunctiontestbackend.php',
        data: {localid: localid,
               firstname: firstname,
               lastname: lastname}
        }).done(function(){ alert('Done with Add/Update!'); });
```

If I create a function at the bottom of the page, or add the function to a js file, this add/update always works.

```
function generalWriteAjax(filetocall, datatosend) {
  $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
           url: filetocall,
          data: datatosend
          }).done(function(){ alert('Done with Add/Update!'); });
                                                   }
```

I would like to detach the .done from the function, and call the .done when attached to a separate function/object. The following code works fine WHEN THERE IS DATA RETURNED FROM THE SERVER. (a separate generalReadAjax function that asks for server data). The done is attached to an object that is returned from the server (This concept I found here on Stackoverflow).

```
  backenddata = generalReadAjax('readtesttablebackend.php');
  displayData(backenddata);
  backenddata.done(function(){ alert("Done with read!"); });
                                   });
```

I have tried all of the following with the WRITE/UPDATE only function, and none of them work.

```
generalWriteAjax(filetocall4update, datatosend4update).done(function(){ alert('Done function'); });

generalWriteAjax(filetocall4update, datatosend4update).when(function(){ alert('Done function'); });

generalWriteAjax(filetocall4update, datatosend4update).then(function(){ alert('Done function'); });

generalWriteAjax(filetocall4update, datatosend4update);
createdonealert = generalWriteAjax(filetocall4update, datatosend4update);
createdonealert.done(function(){ alert('Done function'); });

createdonealert.when(function(){ alert('Done function'); });

createdonealert.then(function(){ alert('Done function'); });
```

So obviously, there is a difference in the way the promise is handled between a "go get me data" and "here is data, please store it".

I even put an `echo "Done";` at the bottom of the update php file just to return something, and still no luck.

I've searched this site and google with combinations of:

ajax .done attach add update not working promise

and have found nothing that deals with my specific example.

Can someone give me some guidance?

I thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well, no one has responded, and I've learned a bit by hacking on this for the last day. Here are some things I THINK I've learned:

1. If you create a general callable function using ajax, it does not act the same as an "inline" ajax - you do not get the same callback actions as you do when the ajax code is at the bottom of an HTML page between script tags.
2. If you return something from the server, the ajax function acts similarly to when it is between script tags.
3. If you DO NOT return data from the server, the ajax function does NOT act the same as when it is inline.

So what I've done is on all php files that are "write/update" only (no data returned), I add a little code to the bottom of each php file that returns a small amount of json "junk". With this "junk" the ajax function acts like a regular ajax call between script tags at the bottom of the page.

It's a kludge, but it works. Here is the code at the bottom of a read/update php file that normally would NOT return anything. It now returns a json array regarding "John":

```
   $json = array('firstname' => 'John');
   echo json_encode($json);
```

Here is the function in the attached js file:

```
function generalWriteAjax( filetocall, datatosend ) {
  return $.ajax({
                   type: 'POST',
                    url: filetocall,
                   data: datatosend,
               dataType: 'json'
                 });
                                                     }
```

Here is the code on the page that calls the .js function:

```
$("#clicktoupdate").click(function(e) {
var localid = $('#idnumber').val();
var firstname = $('#updatefirstname').val();
var lastname = $('#updatelastname').val();
var filetocall4update = 'supdateajaxfunctiontestbackend.php';
var datatosend4update = {localid: localid, firstname: firstname, lastname: lastname};

generalWriteAjax(filetocall4update, datatosend4update).done(function(){ alert('Done inline'); });

});//end of update click
```

I wish I understood the details, but this is an empiric solution that works.

Comments from the experts would be nice.

Thanks for looking!

Comment: What you are doing here looks to be correct. It's exactly the way I would write a generalised utility function. The reason it works is because `generalWriteAjax()` now returns the object returned by `$.ajax()`, which is promise-compatible. You can thus chain `generalWriteAjax().done()` in the same way that you originally chained `$.ajax().done()`.

Comment: Nice, thanks very much. But I wonder about the "callback". When the function is on the same page as the rest of the code, the callback occurs. But when I move the function to a js file, I only get a callback from the server when I put an echo "blah blah" at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Tim, if I understand correctly that's to do with the scope of javascript "members", not specifically to do with Deferreds/Promises. The function must be in scope for it to be callable. Javascript scope is well discussed in many online tutorials, which are easliy discovered via your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thanks! I'll start looking right now! Found a nice review on the Mozilla site - study...study...study...thanks again.